# remove index from vector of type <T> before concatenating two vectors with operator+

Tags: c++, vector, erase

my function takes in 2 vectors, compares the elements in each vector for duplicates. If duplicate is found, I want to erase that element from the second vector.

I get a compiler error when I call the erase method. I believe it's because `Vector<T>` is not the same type as `vector<int>::iterator` but I am not sure how to fix this.

Could someone suggest how would I fix this?

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    typename std::vector<T> newVectorOne = v1;
    typename std::vector<T> newVectorTwo = v2;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = newVectorOne.begin(); i != newVectorOne.end(); i++)
    {
        for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator j = newVectorTwo.begin(); j != newVectorTwo.end(); j++)
        {
            if (*i == *j)
            {
                newVectorTwo.erase(newVectorTwo.begin() + j); //error here
            }
        }
    }
    newVectorOne += NewVectorTwo;
    return newVectorOne;
}
```

error log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Assignment2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\rm\documents\comp3512_2\assignments\assignment2\assignment2.h(67): error C2678: binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\vector(332): note: could be 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator +(int) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\vector(361): note: or       'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> std::operator +<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>(int,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\vector(243): note: or       'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> std::operator +<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>(int,std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\rm\documents\comp3512_2\assignments\assignment2\assignment2.h(67): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\rm\documents\comp3512_2\assignments\assignment2\main.cpp(36): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> operator +<int>(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>Done building project "Assignment2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: When asking a question about a "compiler error" it is very useful to provide the compiler error.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, my bad, I added the error log from VS console

Comment: Thanks asus - with the error message I can tell what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding two iterators together at this line:

```
newVectorTwo.erase(newVectorTwo.begin() + j); //error here
```

Such an operation doesn't exist: you only want one iterator which you increment and dereference, or an incrementing integral offset that you turn into an iterator when deletion is needed. Taking the latter solution as a template, you could change the outer loop so that `j` is `size_t` and goes from 0 to `newVectorTwo.size()` (exclusive).

Keep in mind that `erase` also invalidates iterators **at** and after the point of erasure, so your inner loop is undefined behavior if it actually erases anything (other than the last element, since in that case the loop exits immediately after) - so the approach of using `j` as an incrementing iterator generally won't work as you have it. Using an index into the `vector` solves that: you have no reference to iterators at all except the temporary one created by `begin()`.

### Performance

The performance of your solution will be very poor for vectors of any significant size. The two nested loops and the `erase` call make it an `O(n^3)` solution (more specifically `O(m*n^2)` if `v1` and `v2` have sizes `m` and `n` respectively).

A simpler solution would be just to create `newVectorTwo` initially empty, and then add each element with `push_back` which is *not* a duplicate, rather than trying to remove duplicates from a fully populated vector. This `push_back` runs in `O(1)` amortized time, this will at reduce it to `O(n^2)`. You could also just get rid of `newVectorTwo` and append elements directly to `newVectorOne` and return that. You'd need to change your outermost iteration to use an index though, to get around iterator invalidation.

If you want an expected `O(n)` (actually `O(n + m)`) solution, you could populate a `std::unordered_map` with the contents of `v1` and use that for your lookup, rather than use the two nested loops.

Comment: Efficient in-place is also easy: instead of using `erase`, manually move elements after the first duplicate (and yes, use something better than a linear search).  Track the read and write positions separately, so as you find duplicates the gap widens.  You move each non-duplicate element after the first duplicate in v2 exactly once.  At the end, shrink the vector to discard the old copies.  This keeps your cache footprint small, and you're mostly writing memory which you just read, so you get cache hits.

Comment: @peter a copy is implied here because both arguments are const.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't read the question.  Copying the whole vector and *then* erasing literally made my jaw drop at the inefficiency.  (actually copying *both* whole vectors??)  I assumed the OP must have been talking about in-place modification; your suggestion to make a copy makes more sense now.